# Scrapy - formatting issue outputting data to CSV. Making sure item data prints on separate rows

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, pipeline

I am using Scrapy to scrape information from the first page of a website, and I am exporting the data to a .csv file like so:

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o data.csv
```

I want to get an output of form:

```
{'Title': [u'Message'],
 'Link': [u'url'],
 'Text': [u'Hello World']}
{...........
 .....} etc
```

But instead, I'm getting everything in one {}, i.e.

```
{[all 'Title' data],
 [all 'Link' data],
 [all 'Text' data]}
```

My scrapy spider is as follows:

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from MySpiderProject.items import MyspiderprojectItem


class MySpiderProjectSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "scrapylist"
        allowed_domains = ["url"]
        start_urls = [
        "url/companies/"
        ]


def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('xpath containing each data item'):
            item = MySpiderProjectItem()
            item['Title'] = sel.xpath('xpath for title').extract()
            item['Link'] = sel.xpath('xpath for link').extract() 
            item['Text'] = sel.xpath('xpath for text').re('[^\t\n]+')
            yield item
```

I am scraping from the following URL: http://scrapy.org/companies/
And the xpath expressions are:

```
          response.xpath('//div[@class="company-box"]'):
          response.xpath('//div[@class="companies-container"]'):
          response.xpath('//p/span[@class="highlight"]/text()').extract()
          response.xpath('//a/@href').extract() 
          response.xpath('//p//text()').re('[^\t\n]+')
```

They produce the correct output, as far as I can see.

Can someone explain where things are going wrong here?

Comment: Hm, sounds like your XPath expressions are not correct. Can you post them?

Comment: I have added the xpaths I used, to the question above accordingly - but as far as I can see, they produce the correct output...

Answer (score 1):

You're using [absolute XPaths](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths), which will return all matching tags in the whole file, not only your selector children.

I tried to replicate your project, this generates the desired CSV file:

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from MySpiderProject.items import MyspiderprojectItem

class MySpiderProjectSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scrapylist"
    start_urls = [
    "http://scrapy.org/companies/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.css(".company-box"):
            item = MyspiderprojectItem()
            item['Title'] = sel.css(".highlight ::text").extract_first()
            item['Link'] = sel.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            item['Text'] = sel.xpath('.//p//text()').re('[^\t\n]+')
            yield item
```

I replaced XPath with the CSS selector because they seemed easier to use, and they are also more powerful when [querying for a class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css). I ran it with these arguments:

```
$ scrapy crawl scrapylist -o data.csv
```

Comment: It does indeed work - this resolves my problem now, thanks!

Comment: As soon as I've gained enough reputation to do so, I will mark it as the 'accepted' answer...